# cleveref: configure symbol §/§§ for all sectioning types once time

Tags: sectioning, formatting, cross-referencing, cleveref

I want to configure the section symbol § (singular and plural form §§) indistinctly for all types of sections (part, chapter, section, subsection, paragraph and so on). I use the `cleveref` package, but I don't want this type of customization:

```
\crefname{part}{\S}{\S\S}
\crefname{chapter}{\S}{\S\S}
\crefname{section}{\S}{\S\S}
\crefname{subsection}{\S}{\S\S}
...
```

How can I configure § and §§ for all calls to `\cref`, irrespective of the type of reference?

I've been searching in the `cleveref` documentation but I haven't found/understood how I can do this.

Comment: What's wrong in that code?

Comment: Ugly, unpleasant, repetitous and in general an horror in terms of code readability and design.

Comment: Not uglier than using §. :) Seriously, it's not clear why the package should provide commands that very few people would need. Should it provide also a command for various sets of sectioning commands?

Comment: Hehe, that is right, but I'm writting now a formal document and for differente reasons I want to use that ugly symbol.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\crefnames}[3]{%
  \@for\next:=#1\do{%
    \expandafter\crefname\expandafter{\next}{#2}{#3}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\crefnames{part,chapter,section}{\S}{\S\S}
```

You can use *any* set of sectional commands; this is sufficient for lower levels. If you want to use different symbols for `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph`, just do

```
\crefnames{part,chapter,section}{\S}{\S\S}
\crefnames{paragraph}{\P}{\P\P}
```

Complete example drawn from lockstep's:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\crefnames}[3]{%
  \@for\next:=#1\do{%
    \expandafter\crefname\expandafter{\next}{#2}{#3}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{100}

\crefnames{part,chapter,section}{\S}{\S\S}
\crefnames{paragraph,subparagraph}{\P}{\P\P}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}\label{sec:f}

\section{foobar}\label{sec:fb}

\subsection{foobargnu}\label{sec:fbg}

\subsubsection{foobargnugnat}\label{sec:fbgg}

\subsubsection{foobargnugnat2}\label{sec:fbgg2}

These are references to \cref{sec:f}, \cref{sec:fb}, \cref{sec:fbg}, and \cref{sec:fbgg,sec:fbgg2}.

\paragraph{par}\label{par:p}

\subparagraph{subpar}\label{par:sp}

\subparagraph{subpar2}\label{par:sp2}

References to paragraphs: \cref{par:p}, \cref{par:sp,par:sp2}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In order to avoid problems with spaces in the list of sectional units, you can use `xparse`:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\crefnames}{ m m m }
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 } { \crefname{##1}{#2}{#3} }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

The more complex way you use in your self-answer can be written

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\crefnames}{ m m m }
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \crefformat{##1}{#2####2####1####3}
    \crefmultiformat{##1}
      {#3####2####1####3}
      {and~####2####1####3}
      {, ####2####1####3}
      {, and~####2####1####3}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: +1. BTW, a nice way to suggest that this kind of formatting is "subpar". ;-)

Comment: @egreg Perhaps you could communicate your macro to Toby Cubbit in order to improve his package. Perhaps you are right and very few people needs this type of macros, but it is really a comfortable macro.

Answer (score 15):

I believe it's customary *not* to leave a space between the section symbol generated by `\S` (plural form `\S\S`) and the associated number (or numbers). To achieve this outcome using `cleveref`'s cross-referencing commands, it's necessary to use the "low-level" controls `\crefformat` and `\crefmultiformat`; relying on the "high-level" control `\crefname` doesn't quite get you there, I think. The following MWE is a modified form of lockstep's example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefformat{chapter}{\S#2#1#3}
\crefmultiformat{chapter}{\S\S#2#1#3}{ and~#2#1#3}{, #2#1#3}{, and~#2#1#3}

\crefformat{section}{\S#2#1#3}
\crefmultiformat{section}{\S\S#2#1#3}{ and~#2#1#3}{, #2#1#3}{, and~#2#1#3}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\begin{document}
\chapter{foo}\label{sec:f}
\section{foobar}\label{sec:fb}
\subsection{foobargnu}\label{sec:fbg}
\subsubsection{foobargnugnat}\label{sec:fbgg}

These are cross-references to \cref{sec:f} and to \cref{sec:fb,sec:fbg,sec:fbgg}.

This is how it looks like with just two \cref{sec:fbg,sec:fbgg}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have reason with the spaces. I didn't realize this.

Answer (score 6):

The `cleveref` package contains no built-in way to redefine the cross-reference format of all sectioning levels with a "single-stroke" macro. However, and quoting from section 7.1.2 of the manual,

> [f]or convenience, if they have not been otherwise customised by the
>   end of the preamble, the cross-reference name (and label format) for
>   `subsection` is by default inherited from that of `section`, and that
>   of `subsubsection` is inherited from `subsection` (which might itself
>   have been inherited from `section`). Similarly for `subappendix`,
>   `subsubappendix` and `subsubsubappendix`, and also for `enumii`,
>   `enumiii`, `enumiv` and `enumv`, which inherit from `enumi`. Finally,
>   `subfigure` and `subtable` inherit from `figure` and `table`,
>   respectively.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefname{chapter}{\S}{\S\S}
\crefname{section}{\S}{\S\S}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}\label{sec:f}

\section{foobar}\label{sec:fb}

\subsection{foobargnu}\label{sec:fbg}

\subsubsection{foobargnugnat}\label{sec:fbgg}

These are references to \cref{sec:f}, \cref{sec:fb}, \cref{sec:fbg}, and \cref{sec:fbgg}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very useful your comments about the "heritage" of names. Thank you.

Comment: @Peregring-lk You may also thank me by upvoting my answer. :-)

Comment: @Peregring-lk It's the upward-pointing pen nib, not the checkmark. ;-)

Comment: @lockstep: How do you know who is upvoting (or not)?

Comment: @AlexG I don't. I only know that [Peregring-lk](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/21621/peregring-lk) hasn't cast *any* vote so far. ;-)

Comment: Yes, I know, but I can only upvote one answer, and the egreg's answer is closer to my needs. Anyway, I'have mixed (see below) and thanked all your contributions. But, what is more important, helps and contributions or credentials? :)

Comment: @Peregring-lk You can only *accept* one answer (by clicking on the checkmark), but you can *upvote* as many questions/answers as you want (by clicking on the upward-pointing pen nib). You'll even earn badges for it. :-)

Comment: @Peregring-lk You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Mixing the contributions of @Mico, @lockstep and @egreg, this is my actual integrated customization:

```
\newcommand{\crefnames}[3]{%
   \@for\next:=#1\do{%
     \expandafter\crefformat\expandafter{\next}{#2##2##1##3}
     \expandafter\crefmultiformat\expandafter{\next}
     {#3##2##1##3}{and~##2##1##3}{, ##2##1##3}{, and~##2##1##3}
    }%
 }

 \setcounter{secnumdepth}{100}

 \crefnames{part,section}{\S}{\S\S}
 \crefnames{paragraph}{\P}{\P\P}
```

Finally, a questions about this: if I put a space in the crefnames list, only the first element is taken: for example, in \crefnames{part, section}{\S}{\S\S} only *part* is configurated. Why?

Comment: `\@for` doesn't trim spaces around the various parts of the list. I'll add a way to cope with this to my answer.